# Getting an error and don't understand why

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am at my wits end here. I am writing some procedural code that takes the names of files from an excel worksheet. The code should then find each file recursively starting from a base directory then copy each file to a single location.

My code iterates once then, on the second iteration, produces an error that states that my 'justPath' variable on line 47 cannot be null.

I have posted the code below. Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;

namespace ExcelManip
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {        
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\employee1234\Desktop\Reload_837_X12_Raw.xlsx", 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[4];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
            int actualRows = rowCount - 1;
            int y = 0;
            int z = 1;         
            string targetPath = @"C:\Users\employee1234\Desktop\dropfiles";
            for (int count = 11; count <= rowCount; count++){
                var currentIndex = count;
                var yy = y;
                Console.WriteLine(yy);
                string temp = (string)(xlRange.Cells[currentIndex, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2; 
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\fileshare01\Data\subfolder1\subfolder2\", temp, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                Array.Resize(ref filePaths, filePaths.Length + 1);
                string filePath = filePaths[yy];
                string justPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);     
                string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(justPath, temp);                
                string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, temp);
                Console.WriteLine("File Path " + z+ " of "+ actualRows +" : "+ filePath + "\n");
                System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
                y++;
                z++;
                               }
            xlWorkbook.Save();
            xlWorkbook.Close(0);
            xlApp.Quit();
            GC.Collect();


      }
    }
}
```

Comment: So did you fire up your debugger and check why it *is* null? Maybe one of your filepaths is just the file's name and has no path at all?

Comment: I did debug and also now for a FACT that a path exist for every file in question. So, it's kind of weird. The source path is over a network, but I can't how that would have anything to do with it. Thanks for responding.

Comment: So when you debugged, you found out why it was null? Also, why do you have variables `currentIndex` and `yy` if they just hold the values for `count` and `y`? Why resize the array with one extra element?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a variable `y` that you increment every time in the loop. I assume you think that this line appends to the array:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\fileshare01\Data\subfolder1\subfolder2\", temp, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

It doesn't. It creates a new array. So assuming there is only one file with the name you want, the next time you loop `y == 1` and you're pointing outside the returned results to the null you appended to the array.

If you want to store the actual paths of the files, you need to define a variable outside the loop and add to that. For example a `List<string>`. But since you're just copying, this is not needed.

Also, why duplicating variables like `yy`, `currentIndex` if they just point to variables `y` and `count` which are not modified at all?

And even though you *know* there is always a file with that name, it still doesn't hurt to actually test for this and *when* it happens that a file doesn't exist, you can output an error.

Your loop should be more like:

```
var paths = new List<string>();
for (int count = 11; count <= rowCount; count++){
    string temp = (string)(xlRange.Cells[count, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2; 
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\fileshare01\Data\subfolder1\subfolder2\", temp, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    if ((filePaths == null) || (filePaths.Length == 0))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Didn't find file: " + temp);
      continue; // Or break, or exit, or...
    }
    string filePath = filePaths[0];
    // If the temp is a single filename (no globs), you don't even need the next two lines
    string justPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);     
    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(justPath, temp);                
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, temp);
    Console.WriteLine("File Path " + z+ " of "+ actualRows +" : "+ filePath + "\n");
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
    paths.Add(sourceFile); // or destFile, or what you want to store
    z++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sami. Yeah, I have since modified the code to do an array list as you mentioned. As for the extra variables, these were shots in the dark. I'm too tired to go into detail about the reasoning. So when you say 'define  a variable outside the array', do you mean outside the loop? Thanks again

Comment: @jjones150 Oh, yes, outside the loop. Thanks, fixed it

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I made it clear that I am having to 'look up' the file paths since I don't have them. But I get it with the array/array list so I'll take it out of the loop and see what I can do with that. Thanks again man. I'm new to C# so this really helps,

Comment: Do not use `ArrayList`. It has been obsolete for over ten years. Use `List<T>` instead (for instance, `List<string>`).

Comment: @jjones150 Added a code example for what I think you might want to do. Also if the answer helps you, please select it as accepted with the tick mark

Comment: @JohnSaunders Are you saying, Don't use ArrayList (eg. List<string>); instead, use List<T>? Thanks.

Comment: `ArrayList` is a separate class (named `System.Collections.ArrayList`). You should never use it.

Comment: @Sami. Something you said made me think. It was about the array being reset after every iteration rather than being appended. I used the Directory.GetFiles in the context of an array because I've only seen it used this way and because I lack sufficient experience with C# to deviate too far from examples. However, I made the following modification to my code ->  string filePath = filePaths[0];, along with a few minor clean ups. This seems to work very well. I may try to re-work the code a bit for efficiency, but this helps greatly. Thanks again man!!

Answer (score 1):

`Path.GetDirectoryName` Method from [.NET documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Return Value Type: System.String Directory information for path, **or
>   null if path denotes a root directory or is null**. Returns String.Empty
>   if path does not contain directory information.

Further comment:

> In most cases, the string returned by this method consists of all
>   characters in the path up to but not including the last
>   DirectorySeparatorChar or AltDirectorySeparatorChar. **If the path
>   consists of a root directory, such as "c:\", null is returned.** Note
>   that this method does not support paths using "file:". Because the
>   returned path does not include the DirectorySeparatorChar or
>   AltDirectorySeparatorChar, passing the returned path back into the
>   GetDirectoryName method will result in the truncation of one folder
>   level per subsequent call on the result string. For example, passing
>   the path "C:\Directory\SubDirectory\test.txt" into the
>   GetDirectoryName method will return "C:\Directory\SubDirectory".
>   Passing that string, "C:\Directory\SubDirectory", into
>   GetDirectoryName will result in "C:\Directory".

Comment: Thanks @Oshpho. Got any recs on how to fix the problem. I tried to  concatenate a DirectorySeparatorChar to the end of the but this eliminated the recursiveness of the search.

Answer (score 0):

Array.Resize(ref filePaths, filePaths.Length + 1); this line appends null string to filePaths array. If yy counter goes that far thats it..

Comment: Sorry. How do you think this is related to the error I'm receiving?

Comment: If filePaths[yy] is null then filePath is null what do You expect next? That is if yy reaches end of filePaths